# what is minimum duration requirement for amp-video in amp-story?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

Searching on https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/story_ads_best_practices#video, the documentation only talks about upper limit of video file size.
Are there any limits on the video duration?
I've added videos in my application and the videos just won't play on iphones. It fails with 'Video failed to play' error message at the bottom right corner.
Also warnings seen in the console on desktop as below

```
[video-manager] This video is too short for `video-percentage-played`. Reports may be innacurate. For best results, use videos over 5 seconds long.
```

Comment: AMP Project documentation did not specify a minimum video duration requirement for amp-video within AMP Stories. 

The issue you're encountering with videos may be related to various factors, such as the video format, codec, or how the video is embedded within your AMP Story.

Comment: Right. I am also seeing warnings on the console like below
[video-manager] This video is too short for `video-percentage-played`. Reports may be innacurate. For best results, use videos over 5 seconds long.
Not sure if the documentation is updated or maybe I'm looking at old documentation?